# Bokeh: AjaxDataSource, how to "reuse" JSON data in javascript

Tags: python, bokeh

Using Bokeh 0.12.7 and updating a plot by AjaxDataSource.
This works great.

Now I would like to reuse the data passed to the plot avoiding to read them again from the server again and again.

I would like to access the JSON data file passed to Bokeh javascript from another JS component (i.e. a gauge).

In the example, the gauge is changed randomly but I would like to set it as the last value in the plot. Alas my knowledge of Javascript is null and this doesn't help at all...

Is this possible?

This is the stripped down code I am working on.

```
import numpy as np
from math import sin
from random import random

from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template_string

from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models.sources import AjaxDataSource

html_template = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.7.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">        
        <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.7.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script>

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Label', 'Value'],
                ['value1', 0],
            ]);

            var options = {
                width: 200, height: 200,
                minorTicks: 5
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);

            setInterval(
                function() {

<!-- ***** Change the setValue HERE! ***** -->

                    data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                },
                100);
        }
        </script>

        <div id="gauge_div"></div>

        {{ plot_script | safe }}        
        {{ plot_div.plot_1 | safe }}

     </body>
</html>
"""

x = list(np.arange(0, 10, 0.1))
y = [sin(xx) for xx in x]

source = AjaxDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y),
                        data_url='http://localhost:5050/data',
                        polling_interval=100)

p = figure()
p.line('x', 'y', source=source, color="green")

p.toolbar.logo = None
p.toolbar_location = None

p.x_range.follow = "end"
p.x_range.follow_interval = 200

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main_graph():
    script, div = components({'plot_1': p})

    html = render_template_string(html_template, plot_script=script, plot_div=div)
    return html


@app.route('/data', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    global x, y
    x = x[1:]
    x.append(x[-1]+0.1)

    y = y[1:]
    y.append(sin(x[-1])+random()*.1)

    return jsonify(x=x[-100:], y=y[-100:])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", port=5050)
```